# Building Jenkins from TFS Source Control with Projects outside of the solution folder

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I have a solution with shared projects to other solutions. Those projects are in a different subfolder in TFS.

What is the best way to get these folders in Jenkins. I am using the TFS plugin, but I don't see any options to download more than one folder.

The structure is something like this

Projects
->Main Project
->Project that Main Project depends on

Comment: Are you using  Team Foundation Version Control or GIT?

Comment: TFS version control

Comment: How does your Jenkins, build your project? Is it using msbuild ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using msbuild or any other build tool, you should probably pay attention how to supply dependencies to your build tool. For example msbuild:

> You could use project references for referencing other projects within
>   the same solution. For references which are external to your solution
>   you should use file references, and then check in the **compiled DLL**
>   which is being referenced.

```
Solution1
  \Project1  --> Project1.dll
  \Project2  --> Project2.dll

Solution2
  \ProjectA (references Project1.dll)
  \ProjectB (references Project2.dll)
  \References
      \Project1.dll -- this DLL gets checked in here and ProjectA references from here
      \Project2.dll -- this DLL gets checked in here and ProjectB references from here
```

ProjectA.csproj

```
<Reference Include="Project1.dll, Version=blah blah blah">
   <HintPath>..\References\Project1.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

ProjectB.csproj

```
<Reference Include="Project2.dll, Version=blah blah blah">
   <HintPath>..\References\Project2.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

More detai info please take a look at this question: [How do I get my build agent to build a solution with external project references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708714/how-do-i-get-my-build-agent-to-build-a-solution-with-external-project-references)